# Transformblock not posting to Actionblock

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

Im fairly new to the whole topic and as training I decided to write a GREP clone utilizing what ReactiveExtensions and async/await have to offer.

The following code doesnt propagate the items transformed within transformblock to the resultHandler.

```
    var flowOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true};

    ....

    private static Task _searchTermInFilesAsync(Options options, 
                                                CancellationToken token,
                                                ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions executionOptions, 
                                                ActionBlock<FileSearcherResult> resultHandler,
                                                DataflowLinkOptions flowOptions)
    {
        var enumerator = new TransformManyBlock<Options, FileData>(o => _enumerateFiles(o).TakeWhile(_ => !token.IsCancellationRequested), executionOptions);

        var handleFile = new TransformBlock<FileData, FileSearcherResult>(async data => await _handleFile(options, data), executionOptions);

        enumerator.LinkTo(handleFile, flowOptions);

        handleFile.LinkTo(resultHandler, flowOptions, result => result != null);

        enumerator.Post(options);
        enumerator.Complete();

        return resultHandler.Completion;
    }
```

I have a similiar method working almost the same, the only difference is that there is no transformblock (the other method is used to only enumerate files for the namepattern). Both methods use the same resultHandler so we can assume it works correctly.

So why is the TransformBlock not posting results into the resultHandler? I checked that there are not null results produced.

**EDIT** Apparently the filter is at fault.

```
  handleFile.LinkTo(resultHandler, flowOptions); //, result => result != null);
```

If i comment it out, it works. Strangely there are "notnull" results in there aswell. It seems that the filter stops the whole thing, once it returns false.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, this is probably unrelated to your question, but your return is incorrect. `ContinueWith()` will return `Task<Task>` and you're ignoring the inner task. Since there shouldn't be any reason to explicitly wait for `handleFile`, I would use just `return resultHandler.Completion;`.

Comment: Boiling code down for the complete example.

Comment: @svick updated the question. Also using your first suggestion. Got it working now*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Strangely there are "notnull" results in there aswell.

That's not strange. Each block with output has an output *queue*. Items will leave this queue in the order they arrived (this is also known as [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))). This means that if a `null` arrives and there is no block to receive it, processing will stop.

The easiest solution is to add a block that will accept these `null`s, but do nothing with them:

```
handleFile.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<FileSearcherResult>(), result => result == null);
```

Comment: That did the trick. Guess i completely misunderstood how things work here.